# Need help implementing a blocking bounded mailbox

Tags: scala, akka

I realize it is frowned upon to block in reactive programming ... however, I have a simple use case. I have a Producer than can produce must faster than the pool of Consumers. And for this real-world example, I estimated I only need one Producer and maybe four to 10 consumers (max).

I would like to use a bounded mailbox so that my (Fast) Producer does not get too far ahead of its (Slow) Consumers. In my previous (non Akka) implementation, I used a Java BlockingQueue.

```scala
case object Start
case object End
case class Work(msg: String)

trait Constant {
  val loop = 1000000
}


class SlowConsumerActor extends Actor with RequiresMessageQueue[BoundedMessageQueueSemantics] with Constant with ActorLogging  {
  log.info("created SlowConsumerActor")
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Work(msg) =>
      log.info("working on " + msg)
      Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
}

class FastProducerActor extends Actor with Constant with ActorLogging {
  log.info("Created FastProducerActor")
  val slowConsumerActor = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props[SlowConsumerActor]), "slowConsumerRouter")
  def doWork = {
    for (i <- 1 until 10) {
      val msg = "work" + i
      log.info("Sending " + msg)
      slowConsumerActor ! Work(msg)
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Start =>
      log.info("Got start message in FastProducerActor")
      doWork
      log.info("Sent all messages to Slow Consumer")
  }
}

object BlockingBoundedMailbox extends App {
  val sys = ActorSystem("blocking-bounded-mailbox-example")
  val fastProducerActor = sys.actorOf(Props[FastProducerActor], "producer")
  fastProducerActor ! Start
}
```

application.conf is

```
bounded-mailbox {
  mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedMailbox"
  mailbox-push-timeout-time = 1
  mailbox-capacity = 2
}

akka {
  loglevel = "INFO"
  stdout-loglevel = "INFO"
  actor {
      deployment {
        /producer/slowConsumerRouter {
            router = round-robin-pool
            nr-of-instances = 1
        }
      }

      mailbox.requirements {
        "akka.dispatch.BoundedMessageQueueSemantics" = bounded-mailbox
      }

      default-dispatcher {
        type = "Dispatcher"
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"

      }
  }
}
```

Sample results is

```
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:44:58.497] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Created FastProducerActor
[WARN] [09/01/2019 14:44:58.504] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [mailboxes] Configured potentially-blocking mailbox [bounded-mailbox] configured with non-zero pushTimeOut (1000000 nanoseconds), which can lead to blocking behavior when sending messages to this mailbox. Avoid this by setting `bounded-mailbox.mailbox-push-timeout-time` to `0`.
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:44:58.511] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] created SlowConsumerActor
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:44:58.513] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Got start message in FastProducerActor
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:44:58.515] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sending work1
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:44:58.518] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] working on work1
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:44:59.520] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sending work2
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:00.524] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sending work3
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:01.529] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sending work4
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:01.534] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] Message [com.example.Work] from Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer#-344546494] to Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:02.536] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sending work5
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:02.538] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] Message [com.example.Work] from Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer#-344546494] to Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:03.520] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] working on work2
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:03.541] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sending work6
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:04.546] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sending work7
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:04.548] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] Message [com.example.Work] from Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer#-344546494] to Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:05.552] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sending work8
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:05.553] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] Message [com.example.Work] from Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer#-344546494] to Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860] was not delivered. [4] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:06.556] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sending work9
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:06.558] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] Message [com.example.Work] from Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer#-344546494] to Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860] was not delivered. [5] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a#1170076860]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:07.561] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer] Sent all messages to Slow Consumer
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:08.524] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] working on work3
[INFO] [09/01/2019 14:45:13.527] [blocking-bounded-mailbox-example-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://blocking-bounded-mailbox-example/user/producer/slowConsumerRouter/$a] working on work6
```

The key things --

- I truly want my Producer to slow down or block if the bounded mailbox is full
- I don't want my messages to go to the dead letter queue

BTW, once I get the program working correctly, I will change mailbox-capacity to something larger like 10000 and nr-of-instances to a larger number or use the reSizer to dynamically add more Consumers.

Any help or advice on this long weekend would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer -- and it is really simple. I had set the mailbox-push-timeout-time too low. Hence after a timeout, the messages were going to the dead letter mailbox. I changed mailbox-push-timeout-time to a much larger number which effectively made the single-threaded Producer wait which is what I wanted.